# Unable to GetPathByAction in .net core 3

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

After migrating from .net core 2.2 to 3.0 I ran into an issue with the link generator in .net core.

In 2.2 I could do this and it gave me the path as expected:

```
[Route("/api/store/books")]
public class BooksController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetBooks")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooks(string continuation)
    {
        //...
        var path = linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(HttpContext, nameof(GetBooks), "Books", new { continuation = nextContinuationToken } );
    }
}
```

Now in 3.0 I am getting `null` back, as if the path no longer can be resolved.

I even tried stripping it down to this but I am still getting null:

```
var path = linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(nameof(GetBooks), "Books" );
```

To keep compatability with other configuration I have set `options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;` after moving to 3.0. When using endpoint routing everything works as in 2.2.

Can I use `GetPathByAction` without endpoint routing?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7098

Comment: Thanks, I enabled endpoint routing and changed my configuration and now it works fine.